# Setting only two or three sides and leave the other side(s) untouched

Tags: sass, less

In standard css it's not possible to use `padding: 2px inherit inherit 4px;` instead of

```
padding-top: 2px;
padding-left: 4px;
```

or similarly `padding: inherit 3px;`

Is there any **css-preprocessor** that supports this and similar syntax sugars?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a mixin that caters for what you want (without inherit though) and the code you need to include it would be minimal:

```
@mixin padding($pt: null, $pr: null, $pb: null, $pl: null) {
  padding-top: $pt;
  padding-right: $pr;
  padding-bottom: $pb;
  padding-left: $pl;
}
```

and the consumption:

```
.display {
  @include padding(10, null, 5, null);
}
```